# Modify Kafka Message Content

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

We have no control over the producer of messages sent to our Kafka.  However, we are required to copy the content of those messages to our customer's Kafka topic in agreed specific JSON array structure.

At which stage and how, can we intervene to modify the data to match the required structure?
Can we modify received messages before they become persistent on our Kafka cluster?
Should we modify messages when we copy messages from our Kafka cluster to our Customer's Kafka?
Should KSQL be used to handle it?

Your help is most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question about when to perform the data transformation is more like something you should answer given your context; but the following bullets should help you to decide given the details of how to do it.

**"Can we modify received messages before they become persistent on our Kafka cluster?"** -- While I understand that you have no control over the producers, you could tweak at least the properties that are set to the `KafkaProducer` instance and register an [ProducerInterceptor](https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/2.5.0/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerInterceptor.html) that could grab the message payload, perform de transformation and send somewhere else. The drawbacks of this approach is that you would still need to change the producer code, as well as you would be inserting a callout to another cluster that could bring your throughput down due to the network round-trips. I personally don't recommend this, but it is possible.

**"Should we modify messages when we copy messages from our Kafka cluster to our Customer's Kafka?"** -- Yes. I think this is probably the best approach since ensures that the data ultimately is recorded in your cluster (and therefore you can replay/reprocess as many times you want) before suffering any mutation. In order to implement this you can use Kafka Connect that provides a pluggable set of tools to perform message transformation -- notably, Single Message Transformations and Converters. @rmoff wrote a very good blog that explains how this works: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained.

**"Should KSQL be used to handle it?"** -- Yes. I would strongly recommend since ksqlDB acts as a stream processor on top of the data streaming. Using ksqlDB you count with a great support for possible transformation semantics which goes way above simple per-record/per-aggregation transformations and give you the ability to literally come up with a new data model that can be used to distribute the data that downstream processors are expecting. This is my recommendation.

Regardless of which option you will choose, if the idea is to make the data available in another Kafka cluster different from yours than using MirrorMaker or Confluent Replicator seems to be a good choice. Otherwise, you can simply leverage Kafka Connect and some specialized sink connector to read data from your cluster and send to the destination system that doesn't need to be Kafka.